# Catching the session expiry in pharo seaside 3.2

Tags: smalltalk, pharo, seaside

How to catching the session expiry notification in Pharo Seaside 3.2?
I need remove the user from de active user list when the session expiring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can subclass `WASession` and tell Seaside to use your session instead via the configuration (see `WAApplicationConfiguration>>describeOn:`). In your subclass implement `#unregistered`. This method will be executed when the session has expired (note that this may not happen immediately but only upon the next request to the same application as the this is triggered by the session cache).

Comment: 348/5000
I had tried. The problem I encounter is this:
When the session finishes by timeout and the user tries to login again, the #unregistred method is not executed yet. I use this method to call a method (#logout)) that removes the user from the list of connected users. In this way, the user still appears as connected yet.

Comment: Why don't you store the user in the session?

Comment: I store each user that connects to avoid a double login. If I store it in the session, I do not know how to access it from another session...
Maybe it is my ignorance of the scheme that uses seaside, but should be able to capture the death of the session, for example to present an expiration page. However everything I read is apparently obsolete.

Comment: 1. You can react to expiration by overriding `#handleExpired:` in your application class (subclass of `WAApplication`).
2. I don't see why it matters whether a user is logged in to more than one session at a time. It can even be convenient when you use two browsers to access the page at the same time.

Comment: thank you very much!!I solved it (in part) in that way.
I expected that handler to belong to the class Session...